# Can't refer System.Configuration to References on C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, database-connection

I'm new in C#.NET and I was looking for some tutorials in how to connect a Database in a project. Seeing this videos, in some of them they use the Class "System.Configuration" saying that you have to refer it in the References section of the project. But when I go there and search in the Assemblys, I can't find anything. I even looked one by one and there's no System.Configuration.

[There's the image that shows the Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2poA.png)

[And here's the problem that I got because can't use System.Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTsDG.png)

The video that i used to help in the project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LysPOvCMha

**Edit**

```
    using System;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;


    namespace Lib.DAL
    {
     public class Connection
    {
        public void Conect()
        {
           var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexaoProjetoDB"].ConnectionString;

           using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
           {
            // ...
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

In this code I got an error saying that *"ConfigurationManager doesn't exist in the actual context"* and *"Reference to type 'Component' declares that it's defined in 'System', but couldn't be found"* <- This second one is in "SqlConnection"

I really can't find the error.

That's the code in the Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConexaoProjetoDB" connectionString="Data Source=BRUNA;Initial Catalog=ProjetoDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What type of project are you creating, or in other words, what project template did you select when you created a new project?

Comment: please post more info and the actual code (not as an image). eg. what does intellisense say when you hover the red squirrly line? and if you reference sources you found, it would be helpful if you privided links to them as well.

Comment: @RonBeyer I created a Class Library (Universal Windows) and tried to add the reference in the Reference section there.

Comment: @nozzleman I don't really think the code would be needed because i didn't really write anything but what was in the image, and what about the source, I can post but it's in portuguese thou

Answer (score 0):

The [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)-constructor you are trying to use expects a [ConnectionString](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) as a parameter (string)

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
{
    // ...
}
```

It is common practice to grab that ConnectionString from a config-file (eg *app.config* or *web.config*). 
This can be done using the [`ConfigurationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)-class.

Since you seem to be new to .NET, the following links might be helpful:

- [SqlConnection on DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)
- [Settings on DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/settings)
- [AppSettings on DotNetPerls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/appsettings)

### EDIT

In order to grab the ConnectionString from the config, you can use ConfigurationManager as stated in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx)...

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConexaoProjetoDB"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Well, I did create a ConnectionString but in the Web.config, like this:

**<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConexaoProjetoDB" connectionString="Data Source=BRUNA;Initial Catalog=ProjetoDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlCLiente"/>
  </connectionStrings>**

I was trying to use that by the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, or at least that was what the video i watched said to do.

Comment: @BrunaElize see my edit for details on how to use ConfigurationManager to grab the ConnectionString..

Comment: @BrunaElize also I think you got a typo in your connectionString declaration... *[..] providerName="System.Data.Sql**CLiente**"/>*

Comment: Well, I'm still missing something because I did that, and still can't use ConfigurationManager. I'll put the code and the error in the post